# Android SQLite Join Query

Tags: android, sqlite, join

I'm creating an app as a learning tool and am having difficulty with join queries.

I have a database with two tables- horses and covers- declared as follows;

```
    private static final String HORSES_CREATE = "create table horses (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "name text not null, type integer not null, birthDate text not null, vaccineDate text not null, "
        + "inFoal integer not null, notes text not null);";
```

The 'type' field refers to stallion, mare, gelding etc and is selected from a spinner (populated from an XML String array).

```
private static final String COVERS_CREATE = "create table covers (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "stallionName integer not null, mareName integer not null, firstCoverDate text not null, lastCoverDate text not null, "
        + "scan14Date text not null, scan28Date text not null, foalingDate text not null, inFoal integer not null, notes text not null);";
```

stallionName is actually stored as the _id field of the horse from the horse table. It is selected from a spinner that only displays horses whose type defined as 'Stallion' in the horses table. (The same applies for Mare).

I have a class 'DatabaseHelper' to create and upgrade the tables, and each table has its own adapter class 'horsesDbAdapter' and 'coversDbAdapter' that contains the methods to add, edit and delete entries, and relevant queries. (fetchAllHorses(), fetchHorse(long rowId) )

eg:

```
    public Cursor fetchAllHorses() {

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE,
            new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_TYPE, KEY_BIRTHDATE,
                    KEY_VACCINEDATE, KEY_INFOAL, KEY_NOTES }, null, null,
            null, null, null);
}
```

(It's all adapted from the Android notepad example)

I have the contents of the covers table displayed in a listview (just showing the stallionName and mareName). But as those fields just contain the unique reference to the horses table all that is displayed is the fairly uninformative _id field.

My question is; how can I get the relevant name for the horses to display in the listView? I've read up on join queries etc but get lost when I try implement them. I assume I have to join on horses._id and covers.stallionName (then make an almost-identical one for MareName) but I can't find a concrete example of how to do this.

Please let me know if any additional information/ code is needed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thankyou in advance.

EDIT:
I have made stallionName and mareName foreign keys referencing (_id) in the horses table, but am still unsure how and where to implement the join query; should it be in the horsesDbAdapter, coversDbAdapter or the coversList class? (coversList is the class that creates and populates the listView)
The covers table declaration now reads;

```
    private static final String COVERS_CREATE = "create table covers (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "stallionName integer not null, mareName integer not null, firstCoverDate text not null, lastCoverDate text not null, "
        + "scan14Date text not null, scan28Date text not null, foalingDate text not null, inFoal integer not null, notes text not null," +
        "FOREIGN KEY (stallionName) REFERENCES horses (_id), FOREIGN KEY (mareName) REFERENCES horses (_id));";
```

Comment: you should create in covers table foreign key that referencing to relevant column of horses table.

Comment: @deceiver Thankyou for the input. I've added this to the covers table declaration but I'm still unsure how to actually implement the join and get it to populate a listView

Answer (score 9):

I'm a newbie to Android and SQLLiteHelper and was wondering about the same thing.

After reading this post, I found that the method to define joins between tables is done with the `SQLLiteQueryBuilder.setTables` method. See the [reference here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#setTables%28java.lang.String%29)

I got this from [this blog](http://martin.cubeactive.com/?p=280)

Hope this helps pointing readers in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to get it working. For anyone else who may have a similar problem I'll try detail what I did. 
As @deceiver stated I should have made stallionName and mareName foreign keys referencing horses (see Edit).

In the coversList class (the class that implements the listView) I just needed to get an instance of the database and use a rawQuery to implement the SQL code directly (It may be possible to do it with Query but I'm not sure how)
The added code is as follows;

```
private Cursor coversCursor;
private void fillData() {

    db = (new DatabaseHelper(this).getReadableDatabase());
    coversCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT horses1.name AS stallionNameText, covers.*, horses2.name AS mareNameText FROM horses horses1 JOIN covers ON horses1._id = covers.stallionName JOIN horses horses2 ON horses2._id = covers.MareName",
                    null);
    startManagingCursor(coversCursor);
    // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list
    // (the renamed fields from the above query)
    String[] from = new String[] { "stallionNameText", "mareNameText" };

    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this
    // case just text1)
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.rowStallionName, R.id.rowMareName };

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter covers = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.covers_list_row, coversCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(covers);
}
```

FillData() is then called in the onCreate() method. Then just close the db in the onDestroy method.
(Selecting all columns from the covers table seems wasteful here but I will eventually show these columns in the listView aswell. I just wanted to answer this before continuing coding).
A tutorial I found helpful was http://coenraets.org/blog/android-samples/androidtutorial/

I had issues with the SQL query as there are 2 foreign keys referencing the same table and I wanted the listView to display both the stallion name and mare name, so had to join two horses table to a covers table. I just needed to rename the tables in the FROM section of the SQL query. Hopefully the above code is clear. If not, I found the following useful; http://www.bryantwebconsulting.com/blog/index.cfm/2005/3/11/join_a_table_to_itself_in_sql

Sorry if this explanation is too specific to my (unusual) example.
Thanks for reading.